# sensitivity analysis in docplex

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

how can I do sensitivity analysis in docplex (python)?
Suppose we have this model:

```
 Max z= 3*x+2*y;
  st:
      2*x+y<=8;
      x+2*y<=6;
```

I use docplex in python for solve the model:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
tm = Model(name="MyModel")
x = tm.continuous_var()
y = tm.continuous_var()
tm.add_constraint(2*x+y <= 8)
tm.add_constraint(x+2*y <= 6)
expr = 3*x+2*y
tm.maximize(expr)
result = tm.solve()
```

How can determine the  ranges  of  the  right-hand-side  constants  for  the  constraints  for  which  the  current basis remains optimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use the cplex python object:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
tm = Model(name="MyModel")
x = tm.continuous_var()
y = tm.continuous_var()
tm.add_constraint(2*x+y <= 8)
tm.add_constraint(x+2*y <= 6)
expr = 3*x+2*y
tm.maximize(expr)
result = tm.solve()

cpx = tm.get_engine().get_cplex()

print(cpx.solution.sensitivity.lower_bounds())
print(cpx.solution.sensitivity.upper_bounds())
print(cpx.solution.sensitivity.bounds())
print(cpx.solution.sensitivity.objective())
print(cpx.solution.sensitivity.rhs())
```

Comment: I tried it but I am getting the following error: CplexSolverError: CPLEX Error  1217: No solution exists. Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Hi, you may get this because your model is not feasible. When you do print(result) what do you get ? If you get None then you have no solution.

Comment: Hi, my model is feasible because I am able to print solutions, and when I checked them, they were correct. Is this possible only with continuous variables? Because all of my variables are integer.

Comment: Yes. But you could relax your integer model and then get that. See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoorelaxintegrity.py

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know which would be my solution/result in this case, would it be the 'rs' value ?